# GAE deploy pagespeed warning

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, pagespeed

form this morning (January 12 2016) there is a warning message appearing when we deploy to Google App Engine. We don't use PageSpeed so it's surprising that it tries to post something to its URL.

```
95% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
98% Uploading index definitions.
I 12, 2016 10:45:06 DOP. com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/updatepagespeed?module=yyy&app_id=xxx&version=1&
404 Not Found
You are using a decommissioned API.  Please upgrade to a more recent version of the App Engine SDK which can be found at:https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads
This is try #0
```

We use latest GAE SDK (1.9.30), latest gradle appengine plugin (1.9.30) and gradle task that we run is appengineUpdate.

Why is that Pagespeed warning appearing now and wasn't appearing before? How can we get rid of it?

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: sample problem just happened to me

Comment: yeah same issue here too, updated the app engine sdk and all.. and more  to it. the method i deployed today not working as expected.

Comment: same problem since a few minutes.

Comment: same is happening to me

Comment: the deploy still seems to be successful however

Comment: I have this problem with the latest 1.9.30 Maven plugin and we have no references to pagespeed in appengine-web.xml (or anywhere else)

Comment: I started to get this warning with  version 1.9.27 already and then updated to 1.9.30 but still the same however deploy is successful as for others.

Answer (score 3):

I filed a new bug report here:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12665

Please star it if you are affected. This should help fix the problem upstream, at Google.

**UPDATE 2016-01-20, FIXED**

Quote from Google, see link above:

"This issue is now fixed. Here is a summary of the cause:

The PageSpeed service was switched off on 3rd August. However, the App Engine deployment API continued to have a call for it. A couple of days ago, a new App Engine minor version was released to production, in which this call returns a HTTP 404 and the warning message above. Unfortunately, this App Engine change was released to production before the corresponding change in the App Engine SDK, which is still calling the decommissioned API endpoint. The error message you have received was harmless, the SDK still completed the app deployment.

The SDK team is working on preventative action items that will avoid asynchronous releases."

Comment: Thanks everyone for starring the issue (37) it was accepted by Google engineers and fixed! I just updated my SDk:  google-appengine-java (1.9.30-1 -> 1.9.31-1) . The deploy went smoothly without asking me to update my already updated SDK  ; ) @michalsankot I guess you can mark this answered

Answer (score 2):

Pagespeed has been decommissioned, that's why you're having these problems(although a bit late then expected as it was decommissioned 1.12.15).

For more info: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/pagespeed

Also it's worth checking once in a while:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a reply from Google on this issue**

As people have pointed out above, this is indeed a bug in the SDK — more specifically, an inconsistency between the SDK and the App Engine deployment API.  However, it's harmless: the SDK handles the error gracefully, your app deployments will not be affected, and it's safe to ignore the message.  If you're using the current SDK (1.9.30 at the time I send this message) then you can safely continue to do so.

The reason for the error is that the "updatepagespeed" call is to be removed from both the API backend and the SDK frontend.  Due to an oversight and different release schedules, the API change went out before the SDK change, so the SDK is still invoking the obsolete RPC. Sorry about the noise!  Our engineers are fixing the inconsistency, and we'll make a notification here when the fix has been posted.

Dave Hughes, Google Cloud Platform Support

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, and it was partly caused by a pagespeed entry in appengine-web.xml file.

The second warning is caused by a bug in the Google SDK, but it is harmless, the deploy succeeds. (According to the google comments in the link by CaptainCrunch: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12665)

Answer (score 0):

As toadstool said. Just remove a entry in appengine-web.xml related to pagespeed and done. Thanks everybody for the responses.

I just commented the pagespeed tag I had in my appengine-web.xml

```
<!--
<pagespeed>
    <url-blacklist>http://*/sistema/*</url-blacklist>
    <enabled-rewriter>MinifyCss</enabled-rewriter>
    ...
    ...
</pagespeed>
-->
```

Comment: I have no such entry in `appengine-web.xml`, but I have a `cron.xml`which contains cron jobs Contrary to the log of @michal sankot who sees the warning after the `98% Uploading index definitions.` log entry, I am seeing it after `99% Uploading cron jobs.` Any other place where there might be a reference left?

Comment: Rodrigo could you please post here the entry that you removed, just to be sure that anybody else could check if they have it or not ?

Comment: Luca Stucchi I edited my response to make clear what I did to solve the problem.